# PHP: regex to find comments starting with double slashes //

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to strip single line comments from a string, but leaves URLs untouched. Code should be working with something like this:

```
//Some Comment on http://bobobo.com where bla < 5
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bububu.com"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bababa.com'></script>
```

EDIT: of course I do not use that kind of comment in the HTML file. Correct example would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Some Comment on http://bobobo.com where bla < 5
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://bububu.com"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://bababa.com'></script>
```

My bad, sorry for the mislead.

A possible solution should find "//Some Comment on http://bobobo.com where bla < 5", but not "//bububu.com">" and "//bababa.com'>".

Thanks for any hint...

Comment: Do **NOT** use regex to handle html: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Marc B: Stripping out single line comments would be okay.

Comment: @Tomalak: maybe, but then you're stucking try to figure out if a particular comment is actually a comment, or a url buried in an attribute or is actually a plaintext url.

Comment: @Marc B: That's right. Under the assumption that lines either are comments or not (as the sample suggests), regex would indeed work.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is: don't.**  The reason is that single-line comments are not valid comments in HTML.  They're just text tokens.  You shouldn't have them in your code.  Eliminate them before they are inserted into your source.

---

I tried to give you an alternative answer using PHP's `DomDocument` and `DomXPath`, but it only supports XPath 1.0, and the replace function doesn't exist until 2.0.  I'm not familiar enough with XPath 1.0 to be able to replace a string in the DOM.  Here's what you would need to do though:

1. Select all the text nodes (will ignore attributes because they aren't text nodes)
2. Replace `\s*//.*` (dot does not match a newline) with ''.
3. Insert the text back into the node.

Comment: \s*//.* does not match if the comment is in the first line of the file.

Comment: @Kaii I may be wrong, but I believe that is an implementation detail that may not matter.  You are using replace mechanisms which generally will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, but finally

```
preg_match('!//.*?\n!', $data, $matches);
```

seems to do the trick with or without spaces, tabs or new lines before the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is `^//`.

In `preg_replace()`, you would use the string `'!^//!'`, for example. The `!` is used as a regex delimiter to avoid *leaning toothpick syndrome* (`'/^\/\//'`).

If your lines can start with spaces, you could use `^\s*//`.

Comment: What about comments that are indented by some amount?

Comment: @Marc B: See third paragraph. If things get more complicated than that, very clear rules must be defined (or regex is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this to strip comments that don't appear on a line by itself

```
/(?!http:)\/\//
```

Comment: What about https? ftp? skype? steam?

Comment: @MarcB the OP spoke specifically of http. I suppose it could be written /(?![a-z]+:)\/\//

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace( '~^\h?//(^$)~m', '', $html );
```

Replace // until the end of the line with '', with optional horizontal whitespace before it. Not tested, but something like that should work.